# How to Filter objects by property from a list - Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, collections

I have list of myObjects that contains duplicate values. I need to filter myObjects based on the latest version as shown in the below pic.

[image]

Please share the code either in kotlin (most helpful) or java. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not Java and Kotlin. It's one or the other. And please don't post [images of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: It gives more clarity in screenshot of code like objects property name etc

Comment: You could just say "The constructor takes 3 parameters: name, code and version". Or better yet, show the class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupingBy` and `reduce`
[Kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/4eYZbzsku)

```kotlin
data class MyObject(
    val name: String,
    val code: String,
    val version: Int
)

fun main() {
    val objects = listOf(
        MyObject("Book1", "code_A", 2),
        MyObject("Book1", "code_A", 1),
        MyObject("Book2", "code_B", 3),
        MyObject("Book2", "code_B", 2),
        MyObject("Book2", "code_B", 1),
        MyObject("Book3", "code_C", 1),
    )
    
    val result = objects
        .groupingBy { it.code }
        .reduce { _, a, b -> maxOf(a, b, compareBy { it.version }) }
        .values
    print(result.joinToString(separator = "\n"))
}
```